# Is it possible to add custom events to fullcalendar in angular 7?

Tags: angular, fullcalendar

I want to know if it is possible to add custom events on my calendar not just the standard ones .
And I have no idea how to set [businessHours] on timeGridView

I tried to set them in the html tag or in the optionsInput array from the ts . But it`s not working and I don`t have any error

```
Instead of this: [events]="[
{ title: 'event 1', date: '2019-04-01' },
{ title: 'event 2', date: '2019-04-02' }]" 
can I put my own object? and how ?
and I tried setting the business hours like this :
ngOnInit() {
this.options = {
  editable: true,
  customButtons: {
    myCustomButton: {
      text: 'custom!',
      click() {
        alert('clicked the custom button!');
      }
    }
  },
  businessHours: {
    // days of week. an array of zero-based day of week integers (0=Sunday)
    daysOfWeek: [1, 2, 3, 4], // Monday - Thursday

    startTime: '10:00', // a start time (10am in this example)
    endTime: '18:00', // an end time (6pm in this example)
  },
  header: {
    left: 'prev,next today myCustomButton',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'dayGridMonth'
  },
  plugins: [timeGrigPlugin, interactionPlugin]
};
```

Comment: and html:
   <full-calendar*ngIf="option  #fullcalendar [editable]="true [events]="eventsModel"[header]="options.header
  (dateClick)="openDialog()"
  (eventDragStop)="eventDragStop($event)"[plugins]="options.plugins"
  (eventClick)="eventClick($event)"[businessHours]="options.businessHours"
></full-calendar>

Comment: Are your other options from the same object working? E.g. headers, plugins, custom buttons?

Comment: Yes. the plugin , custom buttons , headers all work fine